# attach image_field to entity in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-fields, imagefield, drupal-entities

I use drupal 7, and Entity API to develope a module.  I have an entity to record client information.  I wish to use image_field to let client upload their logo.  So I have this function:

```
    function silver_client_enable()
{
  field_cache_clear();
  field_associate_fields("silver_client");

  if(field_info_field('logo'))
    return;

  $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'logo',
    'cadinality' => 1,
    'type' => 'image',
    );

    field_create_field($field);

  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'logo',
    'entity_type' => 'silver_client',
    'bundle' => 'silver_client',
    'label' => 'Logo',
    'description' => 'Logo',
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array('label' => 'hidden')
    ),
    'settings' => array(
      'file_directory' => '/logo',
    ),
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'image_image',
     ),
  );

  field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

In the entity creation/edit form, I use :

```
field_attach_form('silver_client', $client, $form, $form_state);
```

to attch the field.

When I called up this form, the image upload field was corrected displayed.  An i can use it to uplod file to serve.

In the form submit function, I save the entity as:

```
entity_save('silver_client', $client);
```

However, after I press the save button, the entity table is correctly saved.  Field table is not.  Both field_data_logo and field_revision_logo are empty.

I believer Entity API looks after the retrieving and saving of attached fields.  Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the values back into your entity:

```
field_attach_submit('silver_client', $client, $form, $form_state);
entity_save('silver_client', $client);
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_submit/7

And you should validate the field values:

```
field_attach_validate('silver_client', $client, $form, $form_state);
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_validate/7

Furthermore if you don't want to declare your entity and fields by yourself you might checkout the `EntityConstructionKit` : http://drupal.org/project/eck which allows to export entity structures with `Features` just like `Views`.

Comment: I like to solve this myself.  In the submit function, function:

 

    entity_form_submit_build_entity('silver_client', $client, $form, $form_state);

need to be called.  Without it, the values come from form_state

Comment: Thanks Ghommey.  In my original code, I did use the field_attach_submit,  but put it after the entity_save.  I didn't really understand the intention of this function.  Now I see, it actually put the field values from form_state into the entity object.  So that these values can be saved later.